# SQLite doesn't work with View EFCore DbContext

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have an Unit Test Project using SQLite as the database fake.

Everything Ok except with the View. It returns an exception

> SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: UserDetails'.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder
         .Entity<UserDetail>()
         .ToView(nameof(UserDetails))
         .HasNoKey();
}
```

Does anyone have the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the view in your database?

If you're using Migrations, you can add a line like this in the `Up` method.

```cs
migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
    CREATE VIEW UserDetails AS
    -- TODO: Write the actual SELECT statement
    SELECT 1;
");
```